# Express/Mongoose/Jest error: ECONNABORTED

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, multer

I've got an API built in Express, which I'm testing with Jest. The API is working just fine when I test with Postman, but when I run my test suite I **usually** get an ECONNABORTED error on my file uploads using .attach(). (Occasionally, it works just fine.) I'm using a suite of middleware to download an array of images referenced by URL, followed by any images passed to the endpoint via form upload. After the images are saved, I'm using a third piece of middleware to resize the images and save them in a subdirectory. Since the error only happens in Jest, it seems like that's where the error would lie, but I'm also not positive I'm handling errors with Multer correctly.

```
// endpoint.js

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: async (req, file, cb) => {
    // Check for product's existence
    if (product) {
      // Make the directory if necessary
      cb(null, /* location */)
    } else {
      cb(404, null)
    }
  },
  filename: async (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null, /* location */}`
    )
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage }).array("files")

router.post(
  "/:id",
  async (req, res, next) => {
    // Download images from URLs if provided
    next()
  },
  (req, res, next) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
      // Handle errors (e.g. return res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found" })
    })
    next()
  },
  async (req, res) => {
    // resize and save to subdirectory
  }
)
```

```
// endpoint.test.js

describe("/endpoint", () => {
  describe("POST", () => {
    it("saves uploaded images to the server", async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post(`/endpoint/${id}`)
        .attach("files", "assets/img-test-1.jpg")
        .attach("files", "assets/img-test-2.jpg")
        .set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")

      expect(response.status).toEqual(201)
    }, 30000)

  ...

})
```

EDIT: The original error was fixed by moving the `next()` call into the Multer handler. However, now the same error is occurring, just on a different test. Again, the error occurs only when running by test scripts; I haven't had any issues when making an identical call via Postman.

```
// endpoint.js

let errors
router.post(
  "/:id",
  async (req, res, next) => {
    errors = []

    ...

    // This is the problematic call. If I explicitly set
    // product = null, the test runs normally
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
    if (!product) {
      errors.push({ status: 404, message: "Product not found" })
      return next()
    }

    ...

    return next()
  },
  // Several more middleware functions
})
```

```
// endpoint.test.js

...

beforeAll(done => {
  app.on("ready", async () => {
    const newProduct = await Product.create(product)
    id = newProduct._id
    done()
  })
})

...
describe("/api/bam/images", () => {
  describe("POST", () => {
    ...
    it("returns a 404 error if the associated product is not found", async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post("/api/bam/images/000000000000000000000000")
        .attach("files", "assets/img-test-1.jpg")
        .attach("files", "assets/img-test-2.jpg")

      expect(response.status).toEqual(404)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might just be related to calling `next()` before multer is done uploading - try moving next inside the upload callback:

```
(req, res, next) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
      // Handle errors (e.g. return res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found" 
      next()
      })
    })

  },
```

PT2: Related to the edit, if it seems that the problem is related to that `await` call then there might be an error being thrown and not caught - when you await a rejected promise it behaves like a normal throw. Throwing here would mean `next` never gets called:

```
    // This is the problematic call. If I explicitly set
    // product = null, the test runs normally
    try {
      const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
      if (!product) {
        errors.push({ status: 404, message: "Product not found" })
        return next()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
```

Comment: This worked the first two times I ran tests on it, but now it's back to failing. I also tried wrapping next() in an else block, but no luck there either.

Comment: Correction: this did fix the error where it was occurring before, but now it's moved to a new location. After further investigation, it seems to be related to Mongoose, but I can't pinpoint the problem. See the edit to the original post.

Comment: @EricToler updated the answer to try to help with the next part

Comment: Finally got back to this project, and this solution seems to have fixed the problem. I still get failures once in a while, but running the tests again has resulted in a pass. I feel like incidental failures are just a side effect of testing with file uploads, and since the problem doesn't seem to exist in production, I can live with occasionally needing to run my tests twice. Thanks!